# Convert columns to one column with talen

Tags: talend

I do an ETL with Talend. To feed the time dimension I have to join two tables. The format of the date in one table is `DDMMYY` and in the other table I have separate fields for year, month, and day. How can I group the 3 fields of the second table to have the first format? What function should I use?

Answer (score 0):

Use TalendDate.parseDate("yy",yearColumn)

Same for month (TalendDate.parseDate("MM",ymonthColumn)) and TalendDate.parseDate("dd",dayColumn) and then concat all three variable in one as ur required format.

Hope this help...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this depends on the field type for year, month, day. Is it a String? Is it a numeric value?

The easiest way to put those fields together *if they are of String type* would be a simple concatenation. Add a new field in e.g. a `tMap` and do the following, according to your job (only works if the values are always 2 digits):

```
row1.year + row1.month + row1.day
```

Then you would be done. If those values are numeric, you'd first convert them to String.

Alternatively, I [always recommend to convert date values in the actual Date format](https://www.tobiasmaasland.de/2017/07/20/using-date-in-talend-etl-jobs/). The post in my blog also explains the difference between the date field on its own and the date format, which could be set to `DDMMYY` whilst still having a valid date value.